# Optimization problem, efficient algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

Solve the following optimization problem (that is, give an efficient
algorithm that finds an optimal solution, and explains why it works):
Given a graph G=(V,E), find the smallest set of new edges (on vertex
set V) to be added to G so that it becomes a connected graph.

In this question, It is not clear form whether the graph G is connected or disconnected. I just tried by considering the graph G is disconnected and I didn't get the said efficient algorithm, any hint and help are appreciated.

Comment: The algorithm should work on any graph $G$. If $G$ is already connected, then the smallest set of edges will be $\emptyset$.

Comment: Hint: start with the case where the graph consists of $n$ disconnected vertices.

Comment: Hint: find all connected components. Then $n$ connected components are regrouped by means of $n-1$ edges.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, do you mean that the graph is initially connected graph?

Comment: @KosovoBuda: why would I have said *all* connected components, then ? Didn't you miss the first comment of Théophile ?

Comment: If you had n disconnected vertices, labeled $v_1$ through $v_n$, then all you have to do is add n-1 edges labeled $e_{1, 2}$ through $e_{n-1, n}$. Now for the graph, think of its connected components as vertices.

Comment: Of course, part of the algorithm would be finding all connected components